# Java BlackJack game using OOP

Tags: java, oop, blackjack

This is my Deck class:

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Deck
    {
private Card[] myCards;
private int numCards;

    // This constructor builds a deck of 52 cards.
public Deck()
{
    int c = 0;
    this.numCards = 52;
    this.myCards = new Card[this.numCards];

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= 13; j++){
            this.myCards[c] = new Card (i, j);
            c++;
        }
    }
  }

public Card deal()
{
    Card top = this.myCards[0];

        for (int c=1; c<this.numCards; c++){
            this.myCards[c-1]=this.myCards[c];
        }
        this.myCards[this.numCards-1]=null;
        this.numCards--;
        return top;
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if (numCards == 0 ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void shuffle(){

    Random rng = new Random();

    Card temp;

    int j;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.numCards; i++){
        j = rng.nextInt(this.numCards);
        temp = this.myCards[i]; 
        this.myCards[i]= this.myCards[j];
        this.myCards[j] = temp;
    }
}

public void printDeck(int numToPrint){
    for (int c = 0; c<numToPrint; c++){
            System.out.printf("% 3d/%d %s \n",      c+1 ,this.numCards, this.myCards[c].toString());
        }

        System.out.printf("\t\t[%d other]", this.numCards- numToPrint);
}
    }
```

This is my Card class

```
     // This class represents one playing card.
     public class Card{

// Card suits (provided for your convenience - use is optional)
public static final int SPADES   = 0;
public static final int HEARTS   = 1;
public static final int CLUBS    = 2;
public static final int DIAMONDS = 3;

// Card faces (provided for your convenience - use is optional)
public static final int ACE      = 1;
public static final int TWO      = 2;
public static final int THREE    = 3;
public static final int FOUR     = 4;
public static final int FIVE     = 5;
public static final int SIX      = 6;
public static final int SEVEN    = 7;
public static final int EIGHT    = 8;
public static final int NINE     = 9;
public static final int TEN      = 10;
public static final int JACK     = 11;
public static final int QUEEN    = 12;
public static final int KING     = 13;


// define fields here
private int suit;
private int face;
private Suit mySuit;
private int cardValue;

public Card(int cardSuit, int cardFace)
{
    this.suit = cardSuit;
    this.face = cardFace;
}

// This method retrieves the suit (spades, hearts, etc.) of this card.
public int  getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}

// This method retrieves the face (ace through king) of this card.
public int getFace()
{
    return face;
}

    public int getValue()
{
    if (face>=2 && face<=10){
        return face;
    } else if (face>= 11 && face<=13){
        return 10;

    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

public String toString(){

    String str = "Error";

    switch(this.face){

    case 1:
        str = " Ace";
        break;

    case 2:
        str = "Two";
        break;

    case 3:
        str = "Three";
        break;

    case 4:
        str = " Four";
        break;

    case 5:
        str = "Five";
        break;

    case 6:
        str = "Six";
        break;

    case 7:
        str = " Seven";
        break;

    case 8:
        str = "Eight";
        break;

    case 9:
        str = "Nine";
        break;

    case 10:
        str = " Ten";
        break;

    case 11:
        str = "Jack";
        break;

    case 12:
        str = "Queen";
        break;

    case 13:
        str = " King";
        break;

                }
    return str + " of " + this.suitToString(suit);
}

public String suitToString(int a ){

    String b;
    if(a == 0){
        b = "Spades";
        return b;
    }else if (a == 1){
        b = "Hearts";
        return b;
    }else if (a == 2){
        b = "Clubs";
        return b;
    }else {
        b = "Diamonds";
        return b;
    }
}
}
```

This is my Player class:

```
    public class Player {

public String name;
private double bankRoll;
private Card[] hand;
private double currentBet;
private int numCards = 0;

public double getCurrentBet() {
    return currentBet;
}

public void setCurrentBet(double currentBet) {
    this.currentBet = currentBet;
}

public double getBankRoll() {
    return bankRoll;
}

public Card[] getHand() {
    return hand;
}

public Player(String name, double amount){
    this.name = name;
    this.bankRoll = amount;
    this.currentBet = 0;
    this.hand = new Card[11];
}

public void resetHand(){
    this.hand = new Card[11];
    this.numCards = 0;
}

public String toString(){
    return this.name + " - $" + this.bankRoll + printHand();
}

public void addCard2(Card c){
    this.hand[this.numCards] = c;
    numCards ++;
}

public String printHand(){
    String handString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<this.numCards; i++){
        handString += this.hand[i] + ";" ;
    }
    return handString;
}
public boolean addCard(Card aCard){

    if(this.numCards ==10){
        System.err.printf("%s's hand already has 10 cards\n", 

    this.name );
        System.exit(1);
    }
    this.hand[this.numCards]=aCard;
    this.numCards++;
    return(this.getHandSum()<=21);
}
public int getHandSum(){
    int handSum = 0;
    int cardNum;
    int numAces = 0;

    for (int c=0; c<this.numCards; c++){
        cardNum = this.hand[c].getValue();

        if(cardNum == 1){
            numAces++;
            handSum+=11;
            } else if (cardNum > 10){
                handSum+=10;
            }else {
                handSum += cardNum;
            }

    }

    while (handSum >21 && numAces > 0){
        handSum -= 10;
        numAces --;
    }

    return handSum;
}

public void showHand(boolean showFirstCard){
    System.out.printf("%s's cards:", this.name);
    System.out.println();
    for(int c = 0; c<this.numCards; c++){
        if(c==0 && !showFirstCard){
            System.out.println(" [hidden]");
            } else {
                System.out.printf(" %s", this.hand[c].toString());
                System.out.println();
            }
    }

}
private int face;

public int getFace()
{
    this.face = face;
    return face;
}
```

}

This is my main game loop:

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 

    public class Blackjack {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Deck myDeck = new Deck();
    myDeck.shuffle();

    System.out.print("Enter number of Players (Max 6): ");
    int numPlayers = IO.readInt();
    double[] playersBank = new double[numPlayers];
    if (numPlayers<0 || numPlayers>6){
        IO.reportBadInput();
    }
    Player[] player = new Player[numPlayers];
    Player dealer = new Player ("Dealer", 0);

    for (int i =0; i<numPlayers; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter player's name: ");
        String playerName = IO.readString();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter player's starting balance:");
        double startingBalance = IO.readDouble();
        System.out.println();
        playersBank[i]= startingBalance;
    Player a;

            a = new Player(playerName, startingBalance);
        player[i] = a;

        System.out.print(player[i]+ " ");
        System.out.println();

        }
    double currentBet;
    double[] bets = new double[player.length];

    for (int i=0;i<player.length; i++){

        System.out.println(player[i]+" "+"enter current bet:");
        currentBet = IO.readDouble();
        if(currentBet> player[i].getBankRoll()){
            System.out.println("That is greater than the amount in your account");
            return;
        }
        bets[i]= currentBet;

    }

    for(int i = 0;i<player.length; i++){

            player[i].addCard(myDeck.deal());
            player[i].addCard(myDeck.deal());
            player[i].showHand(true);
            System.out.println(player[i].getHandSum());
        }

    for(int i=0; i<1;i++){
        dealer.addCard(myDeck.deal());
        dealer.addCard(myDeck.deal());
        dealer.showHand(false);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<player.length; i++){
        dealer.showHand(false);

        if(dealer.getHandSum() - 10 == 11){
            player[i].showHand(true);
            System.out.println("Would you like insurance? (y) or (n)");
            String ans = IO.readString();
            ans.toLowerCase();
            if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
                System.out.println("How much would you like to bet?");
                int answer = IO.readInt();
                if(dealer.getHandSum() == 21){
                    playersBank[i] -= bets[i];
                }
                }

        }

        }

    for(int i=0; i<player.length;i++){

        int numCards = 2;
        boolean playerDone = false;
        boolean dealerDone = true;
        String ans = "";
        boolean doubleDown;

        if(player[i].getBankRoll() - bets[i] > 0){
        System.out.println(player[i].name+" Your hand value is: "+ player[i].getHandSum());
        System.out.println("Would you like to double down? (Y or N)");
        ans = IO.readString();
        ans.toLowerCase();

        if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ){
            player[i].addCard(myDeck.deal());
            bets[i]= bets[i]*2;
            doubleDown = true;
            player[i].showHand(true);
            playerDone = true;

            }}else {break;}

        System.out.println(player[i].name+" Your hand value is: "+ player[i].getHandSum());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to hit 2 to stay");
        System.out.println(player[i].getHandSum());
        int answer = IO.readInt();
        while(answer == 1 && player[i].getHandSum()<21){
             player[i].addCard(myDeck.deal());
             player[i].showHand(true);
             if(player[i].getHandSum() > 21){
                 System.out.println("You busted");
                 playerDone = true;
                 break;
             }
             System.out.println();
             System.out.println(player[i].name + "Your hand value is: " + player[i].getHandSum());
             System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Enter 1 to hit 2 to stay");
                answer = IO.readInt();

        if(player[i].getHandSum() > 21){
             System.out.println("You busted");
             playerDone = true;
         }else if (answer == 2){
            playerDone = true;
            dealerDone = true;
            continue;

        }

        }

        boolean allPlayersDone = true;
        dealerDone = false;

    if(allPlayersDone && !dealerDone){

        dealer.showHand(true);
        System.out.println();

        if(dealer.getHandSum()==21 && dealer.getHand().length == 2){
            System.out.println("Dealer has blackjack");
            dealerDone=true;
        }else while(dealer.getHandSum()<17){
            dealer.addCard(myDeck.deal());
            dealerDone = false;
        }}else if(dealer.getHandSum()>=17 && dealer.getHandSum()<22){
            System.out.println("Dealer Stays.");
            System.out.print(dealer + "Hand value is:" + dealer.getHandSum());
            dealerDone = true;
        }
    }

boolean winCheck = true;

if(winCheck == true){
for (int i=0; i<player.length;i++){
int playerValue = player[i].getHandSum();
int dealerValue = dealer.getHandSum();

    player[i].showHand(true);
    dealer.showHand(true);
    System.out.println();
    if(playerValue > 21){
        System.out.println(player[i].name + " You Busted You Lose " + bets[i] + " will be deducted from your account." + " $"+ playersBank[i] + " is left in your account");
        double temp = playersBank[i] - bets[i];
        playersBank[i] = temp;
    }
    if(dealerValue > playerValue){
        System.out.println( player[i].name + " You lose "+ bets[i]+ " Will be deducted from your account" + " $"+ playersBank[i] + " is left in your account");
        double temp = playersBank[i]-bets[i];
        playersBank[i] = temp;
    }else if(dealerValue > 21 && playerValue <= 21 ){
        System.out.println(player[i].name + " You win "+ bets[i]+ " Will be added to your account" + " $"+ playersBank[i] + " is left in your account");
        double temp = playersBank[i]+bets[i];
        playersBank[i] = temp;
    }else if(playerValue==dealerValue){
        System.out.println(player[i] + " Push:  Bet is unchanged"+ " $"+playersBank[i] + " is left in your account");

    }
}
}
}

    }
```

I have to incorporate a Split hand feature that is common in most casino blackjack games.  The problem that I am having is calling and comparing the two cards in the players hand.  Every time I try to call the elements of the Card array that is part of the Player object it gives me errors.  The program is also not deducting or adding the bets to the player's balance.

I also need to add a basic statistic and hint system to each player as he plays.

Any help on how I can make this more effective or any bugs you see would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take the tour and read the help center to understand how to use Stack Overflow.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am a complete novice at programming.

Comment: No, you mentioned it, but I edited it out. It's irrelevant. Please take the tour and read the help center to understand why.

Comment: I am having trouble incorporating a split hand feature.  I try to call up the cards in the Players card array and compare them to each other.

Comment: I used the command player[I].card[0] and it gives me an error saying that card is not defined in the player class.  But in the Player class I created a card array which is unique to each new player.  How do I call the cards in the hand and compare them effectively in order to be able to put that feature in the game?

Comment: Please format all of your code properly.  And get rid of unnecessary blank lines.  (Any occurence of 2 blank lines in a row contains 1 unnecessary blank line.)

Comment: Please explain what "split hand feature" means.  We come from all over the planet, not only from places where black jack is played. Also, we are programmers, we are not gamblers.

Comment: If the first two cards in a player's hand have the same face (for example both cards are Kings) then the player has the option to double his initial bet and "split" the cards into two hands where he gets an additional card for each hand (for example the two kings separate and each king gets an additional random card from the deck).  The player would then have the option to play each hand separately.

Comment: On web sites like stackoverflow.com phrases like "it gives me errors" do not pass as acceptable descriptions of technical problems.  Please explain ***precisely what error*** and ***precisely on which line***.  Please put that in the question, do not leave it in a comment.  It is ***not*** some unimportant detail.

Comment: You still have not reformatted any of that code.

Comment: Ok hopefully the formatting is better @Mike Nakis.  The exact error I have is that in the final for loop after Boolean winCheck = true; The wager amounts aren't changing regardless of whether the player won the hand or not.

Comment: Also like I said I am clueless as to how to even implement the split hand feature I explained earlier.

Comment: @SolidSpectre I am sorry, but I do not call that an improvement of the formatting.  Do you know that Eclipse will reformat all of your code by simply pressing Ctrl+Shift+F?

Answer (score 0):

These are my notes up until the point where I gave up.  I gave up because the bad formatting is sabotaging my efforts to read the code.

Also, it appears to me that the regions with the worse formatting are also the ones that contain the most nonsensical code, so I am beginning to suspect that there is something fishy going on, like perhaps two programmers involved, one who does not understand squat trying to finish the job of another who perhaps understood a couple of things.

---

I would recommend using an `ArrayList<Card>` instead of a `Card[]`, but if your assignment mandates arrays, then fine, stick with arrays.

I would recommend that you stop using `this.` all the time, but if your professor requires you to, then oh well, what can you do.

Your entire `isEmpty()` method could be coded as `{ return numCards == 0; }` but what you have is not wrong, it is just silly.

Your suits and faces should really be `enum`s instead of large groups of constants.  That's not an error, but the fact that your faces constants begin from 1 instead of 0 may cause problems.

Your `suitToString()` should really be implemented with a `switch` statement.  (Not an error.)

Your Card.mySuit and Card.cardValue members make no sense, and they do not appear to be used anyway.

Card.mySuit appears to be of type `Suit`. So, finally, do you have a `Suit` enumeration, or not?  Are you hiding something from us?

In `printHand()` you should really be using a `StringBuilder`.  But, not an error.

When you encounter an error, ***don't*** `System.err.printf()` and `exit()`.  Throw an exception instead.  But, not an error.

The following code makes no sense:

```
private int face;

public int getFace()
{
    this.face = face;
    return face;
}
```

***and*** it does not even make any sense for a player to have a face.
Luckily, it is never used.  Get rid of it.

Just so that you know, this:

```
Player a;
a = new Player(playerName, startingBalance);
player[i] = a;
```

gets simplified to this:

```
Player a = new Player(playerName, startingBalance);
player[i] = a;
```

which gets simplified to this:

```
player[i] = new Player(playerName, startingBalance);
```

Please do not waste our time forcing us to read mindless lines of code.

In `main()` you declare some `double[] playersBank`, but then each player has their own `bankRoll`, which does not make any sense to me.  I may be wrong, but I think one of them needs to go.  I would recommend getting rid of `playersBank`.  That's probably an error.

Yes, of course the program is not deducting or adding the bets to the player's balance, you have not written the code to do that.  But that should be trivial for someone who has already written so much code. Have you by any chance copied this code from someone else without having any clue as to how it works and what it is trying to do?

Anyhow, near `bets[i]= currentBet;` of course you need to subtract `currentBet` from the player's balance.  That's an error.

Also, I would recommend losing the `bets[]` array and moving the `currentBet` into the `Player` class.  But that's not an error.

---

As for the split hand feature, you will probably have to add a `Card[] splitHand` member to `Player`, which, if non-null, means that the player has split their hand.  And you will need to write the code that asks for it, and does it.  We here find problems with peoples' code, and suggest solutions, we don't usually write peoples' code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Some of the objects and constructors were covered in class so with the professors permission the students copied the code. I have a very basic understanding on coding. And things got messy when bugs kept coming up and I tried cheap fixes to get the program in some sort of working error. I think regardless of the outcome I have proven that I don't understand this and need to take the class again. Thanks for your help though it is really appreciated.